# Какой компилятор использовать..

Tags: компилятор, java

День добрый уважаемые.
Позвольте вопрос.
Я приступаю к изучению Java и хотел бы посоветоваться с вами, какой компилятор использовать для написания кода на Java ?
Выпускает ли компания http://www.embarcadero.com/ продукт для создания Java аплетов и скриптов..?

Благодарю всех за посильную помощь в совете.

Answer (score 3):

> ... аплетов...

Еще 5-6 лет назад, аплеты "рулили", но сейчас они практически нигде не встречаются, т. к. имеют некоторые проблемы с безопасностью, и программисты их стараются обходить стороной.

> ... и скриптов...

Java — это не скриптовый язык, а язык, который компилируется в байткод, затем этот байткод (во время выполнения приложения) либо интерпретируется либо может быть скомпилирован JIT 
компилятором в машинный код.

> какой компилятор использовать для написания кода на Java

Язык Java официально принадлежит компании Oracle, и для написания приложений на этом языке можно использовать JDK - Java Development Kit от этой же компании (там уже есть компилятор - JavaC): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Из книг могу посоветовать две:

- [**Брюс Эккель, "Философия Java"**](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9785496009546%2C+9785496011273%2C+9780131872486&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0)
- [**Герберт Шилдт, "Java 8. Полное руководство"**](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9785845919182%2C+9780071808552&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0)

И если вы совсем новичок в программировании, то обратите внимание на эту книгу:

Файн Я. Программирование на Java для детей, родителей, дедушек и бабушек

Answer (score 2):

> какой компилятор использовать для написания кода

Компилятором обычно компилируют, а код пишут в редакторе или IDE.

Для *написания* кода можете использовать бесплатную IDE на свой вкус: InjellijIDEA, Netbeans, Eclipse.

---

Опровергну [@tch74](/users/19639/tch74), у Embarcadero действительно есть среда разработки для Java - [JBuilder](http://www.embarcadero.com/ru/products/jbuilder) и  J Optimizer, но я не стал бы ее рекомендовать:

- из-за того, что последняя версия - 2009 и новых не ожидается
- из-за оторванности от жизни и экосистемы java
- из-за маркетинговой политики эмбаркадеров и конских ценников

Comment: Спасибо, что поправили, а то я как то упустил из виду эти два продукта: JBuilder и JOptimizer. Я сейчас исправлю свой пост.